# Dual Monitor with integrated and discrete GPU on Debian

Tags: debian, drivers, gpu

I've got an Asrock Extreme 3 motherboard and a Nvidia 660ti GPU.

I was trying to configure dual monitor on debian 7 connecting one monitor to the mb and the other to the GPU. This configuration works perfectly on Windows 7 without installing any drivers.

With debian only the GPU monitor is working. When I try to connect the second to the motherboard it shows the following:

```
Decompressing Linux... Parsing ELF... done.
[    0.0000000] tsc: Fast TSC calibration failed
Loading, please wait...
[    3.222458] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[    3.222518] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
INIT: version 2.88 booting
[info] Using makefile-style concurrent boot in runlevel S.
[ ok ] Starting the hotplug events dispatcher: udevd.
[ ok ] Synthesizing the initial hotplug events...done.
[....] Waiting for /dev to be fully populated...
```

After a few minutes it turns off.

This only occurs when I hotplug it. If I start the system with the monitor connected it doesn't turn on.

How can I configure it?

Comment: Are you using nouveau or proprietary drivers? Is your integrated GPU from intel?

Comment: Can you provide the output of `xrandr --verbose`?

Comment: nouveau drivers and the iGPU is from Intel. Intel HD Graphics 4000 I think.

Comment: xrandr --verbose only displays the nvidia card ports (hdmi and dvi). It doesn't show the motherboard ones (another hdmi, dvi and vga).